# What is the Difference between onRestart() and onStart()

Tags: android

Here i am trying to run a timer and its working fine, But my confusion is between `onRestart()` and `onStart()` method both are working same for me even after rotating the device, where in `Head First Android book` it is stated that:

> " : When you rotate the device, the activity is destroyed and a new one is created in its place. If we’d put code in the onRestart() method
>   instead, it wouldn’t have run when the activity was re-created. The `onStart()` method gets called in both situations."

Can please anyone help to clarify this.

```
private int seconds = 0;
    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean wasRunning = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch_revision);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){

            seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
            running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
            wasRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("wasRunning");

        }
        runningTime();
    }
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle sv){

        sv.putInt("seconds",seconds);
        sv.putBoolean("running",running);
        sv.putBoolean("wasRunning",wasRunning);

    }

    public void onStop(){

        super.onStop();
        wasRunning = running;
        running = false ;


    }


    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        if (wasRunning) {
            running = true;
        }
    }
  /*Removing the onStart() method and adding the onRestart() method gives the same result*/ 

    public void onRestart() {

        super.onRestart();
        if (wasRunning) {
            running = true;
        }
    }

    public void runningTime() {

        final TextView txt_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                int hours = seconds / 3600;
                int mins = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                int secs = seconds % 60;
                String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, mins, secs);
                txt_time.setText(time);

                if (running) {


                    seconds++;
                }

                new Handler().postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }


        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As from the Documentation It shows that when the activity is stopped the method `onStop()` is called. To come from the `onStop()` you have to pass `onRestart()` first.
**Here is the general difference:**
`onStart()` will always be called whenever you enter your `Activity` just after `onCreate()` but the `onRestart()` will only be called before `onStart()` when your Activity comes from being stopped (passing from `onStop()`) back to the running in front of user. The whole description can be summarised by the image below:
[image: activity life cycle].
 You can get more description [from the following link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 1):

`onRestart()` is called only if `onStop()` has been called before

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

The activity was stopped and you are RE-starting it hence `onRestart()`.
The very first time or after the activity has been destroyed it's just `onStart()`

Answer (score 0):

Both are activity lifecycle methods. onStart() will get called every time when you create an activity. onRestart() will be called once activity goes to background and comes to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android activity state cycle]

As you can see from the android activity state cycle, `onStart()` and `onResume()` are both called when the visible lifetime starts.

An Activity’s visible lifetimes are bound between calls to onStart and onStop. Between these
calls your Activity will be visible to the user, although it may not have focus and may be partially
obscured. Activities are likely to go through several visible lifetimes during their full lifetime
because they move between the foreground and background